# =LEFT(H2,5) To show data for all rows and stop at last row of data

Tags: vba, excel

Hi could someone enlighten me with some VBA code to insert formula =LEFT(H2,5) into column M and then stop at the last row of data. 
The data it will be referencing will be inserted from the web so when i refresh the data pull the rows could be more or less so it can't be a fixed without using VB

Thanks
Rhys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range("M2:M" & N)
    r.Formula = "=LEFT(H2,5)"
End Sub
```

You will find that the addresses in the formulas adjust just like in copy/paste.

Comment: This works great thanks but i can't get it to Run on the click of a button which is on another sheet, but i'll try and work it out

Comment: @Mils  Note that this is only demo code...............you must adapt it to meet your specific needs.................

Comment: Yes Gary I get that I just wanted to say thank you to show my appreciation, I lost touch with coding cause I haven't done it for years after leaving uni and just trying to get back into it step by step

Answer (score 1):

Would a while loop work for you?

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2 'starting row number
While Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" 'Empty row
    Cells(i, 13).Formula = "=LEFT(H2,5)" 'replace this with something for that row, concatenating i to H will work i think.
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

You'll also want to put this code to whenever the data is refreshed so it inserts the formula to all rows again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim x As Long

x = Application.CountA(ActiveSheet.Columns(13))

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13) = "=LEFT(H2,5)"

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Resize(x - 1).Formula = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Formula
```

use excel function CountA to get the total number of row that you need to populate and assign that number to x

then put the actual formula on cells M2 then copy the formula until the last row using resize function